Configure VSCode for PHP formatting
I would like to configure VSCode for my preferred PHP formatting. Like I need isset( $_GET[ 'action' ] ) not  isset($_GET['action']) while I format code in vscode.
How can I do that  ?


Install PHP-CS-Fixer Globally:
composer global require friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer


Update .php-cs-fixer.dist.php: Configure the PHP-CS-Fixer rules:
return (new Config())
    ->setRiskyAllowed(true)
    ->setRules([
        'array_syntax' => ['syntax' => 'short'],
        'binary_operator_spaces' => ['default' => 'single_space'],
        'space_inside_parentheses' => true,
        'custom_spaces_in_brackets' => true,
    ])
    ->setFinder(Finder::create()->in(__DIR__)->name('*.php')->exclude(['vendor']));


Create Custom Fixer for Brackets:
Implement a custom fixer:
class CustomSpacesInBracketsFixer extends AbstractFixer {
    public function fix(\SplFileInfo $file, Tokens $tokens) {
        foreach ($tokens as $index => $token) {
            if ($token->getContent() === '[') $tokens->ensureWhitespaceAtIndex($index - 1, 0, ' ');
            if ($token->getContent() === ']') $tokens->ensureWhitespaceAtIndex($index + 1, 0, ' ');
        }
    }
}


Register Custom Fixer:
Add to .php-cs-fixer.dist.php:
->registerCustomFixers([new CustomSpacesInBracketsFixer()])


VSCode Configuration:
Add to settings.json:


{
     "[php]": {
               "editor.defaultFormatter": "junstyle.php-cs-fixer"
               },
               "php-cs-fixer.executablePath": "~/.composer/vendor/bin/php-cs-fixer",
               "php-cs-fixer.onsave": true
           } 


Run PHP-CS-Fixer:
php-cs-fixer fix



Alternative:

PHPStorm directly supports custom formatting rules and might be an easier option for seamless configuration.

